# How to link to the extension-affected version of a page from within an iframe?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

Let me explain. My chrome extension consists of this:

- Injecting an html page in an iframe
- Inside this html page is another iframe sourced to an external site
- This external site is being modified by the extension also

The problem is I am not seeing the effects I should be. How do I specify I want to display the version of my site affected by the extension?

Edit: Here is the exact part of the code that Im working with:
 `<iframe id="wikiforum" src="http://mudandblood.net/html/modules.php?name=Forums"></iframe>`

That url its currently pointing to is also having css and js injected into it by my extension. Everything works how it should when I visit the site directly, but through the iframe it remains unchanged. Thats what I'm trying to fix.

2nd Edit: Yes, I am injecting the content scripts through the manifest. Like so:

```
{
    "name": "MnB2+",
    "version": "1",
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "content_scripts": [
        {
        "js": ["contentscript.js"],
        "matches": ["http://mudandblood.net/mudandblood2.swf","http://www.mudandblood.net/mudandblood2.swf"],
        "all_frames": true
        },
        {
        "css": ["style.css"],
        "js": ["csforum.js"],
        "matches": ["http://mudandblood.net/html/*"]
        }
    ],
    "permissions": [ 
   "tabs"
],
    "web_accessible_resources": [
        "irc.html",
        "wiki.html",
        "style.css",
        "vectors/*.svg"
    ]
}
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. I suggest you to add the relevant code to your question.

Comment: Please add how are you injecting your content scripts. If you do it through the manifest, include the section in your question.

Answer (score 1):

So I'm a dolt and a noob, I solved my own problem. Downvote me as you will, I apologize sincerely. Wouldn't have figured it out though if I didn't post here.

The key was I didn't include `"all_frames": true` in the second content script section. Hope this at least helps another newbie on the way.